# Plot a Piecewise with different value of n

Tags: plotting

Hi I need help to fix my issue , I need to plot the following code for n values `f[y_] := Piecewise[{{1, (2 n + 1) <= y <= (2 n + 2)}, {0, True}}]`
n=-1,-2,-3,4,5,5

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
f[n_][y_] := Piecewise[{{1, (2 n + 1) <= y <= (2 n + 2)}, {0, True}}]

Plot[Evaluate[f[#][y] & /@ {-1, -2, -3, 4, 5}], {y, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you , but not work what  you did

Comment: @user55346 What you mean?

Comment: i meant your code does not work when I run it

Comment: @user55346 Quit kernel then run it again

Comment: Note that `f = Function[n,
   Function[y, 
    Piecewise[{{1, (2 n + 1) <= y <= (2 n + 2)}, {0, True}}]]
   ];` can also come in handy in many cases.

Comment: @user55346 Putting `ClearAll[f];` before the definition of `f` is good practice, because of the way definitions in *Mathematica* can accumulate. I always do it, and usually do it in my answers on this site.  It saves headaches.